# Why in Java variables don't get invalidated when an ArrayList reallocates?

Tags: java, oop

I want to know how does Java's runtime know where an object is located. Why does this code work:

**Class A**

```
class A{
    int id;
    A(int i){
        id = i;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
ArrayList<A> array = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    array.add(new A(i));
}

A fifth = array.get(5); // this object will be reallocated soon

for(int i=10; i<1000000; i++){
    array.add(new A(i));
}

System.out.println("it's still alive " + fifth.id); // works, but why?
```

How exactly are the variable name bound to the actual object? Is this managed at runtime?

**Edit:** I just figured out the answer myself and it's because the array underneath `ArrayList` contains pointers to objects, but these objects themselves are all the time in the same location. Only the array of pointers move. I've been doing C++ all evening and my mind was stuck with thinking of vectors that contain non-heap elements. That's why I confused this.

Comment: `this object will be reallocated soon` ... you never reinitialize `fifth`, nor do you mess with any of the values inside the array list, in the second loop.  Hence, I don't understand your question.

Comment: A variable is just a reference to some point in memory (you just don't get all the fun pointer stuff like C/C++), so `fifth` is pointing to the same location as `array.get(5)` is, they are the same thing ... as a very basic level description

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm talking about a different thing. I'm talking about the memory reallocation of the ArrayList that takes place when I add many more items. Why does `fifth` still know where the object is, even if the array of the ArrayList has moved to a different physical memory location.

Comment: I believe Java's `ArrayList` is implemented under the hood just using an array.  If you have a reference to the fifth entry in an array, and you don't change either the variable reference _or_ the underlying data, then why does your current output surprise you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because `ArrayList`s have dynamic size, and they reallocate to different memory locations when they grow.

Comment: Yes, the JVM may increase the size of the underlying array, but it will dutifully copy all elements into the same positions AFAIK.  So this still should not be a problem.

Comment: @FeloVilches It kind of does, because it's still just a memory reference, you're not moving the physical object to somewhere new, you're just making, what ever new array is created, point to the same point in memory

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, it's like a `realloc` in C. It copies all elements to a bigger memory segment. But why does `fifth` still know where the element is?

Comment: @FeloVilches Because it's not changing the point in memory to which it points to, it just moves the pointer to a new location in memory, so both element 5 and `fifth` still point to the same memory location where the object resides

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. It's not CHANGING THE POINTER which resides at element 5, it still points to the object, the fact that the "pointer" (in the array) might have moved to a new location is irrelevant, it will still point to the same point in memory ... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've annotated your source code a little further. :)

```
ArrayList<A> array = new ArrayList<>(); // allocates a single ArrayList object 
// the ArrayList contains an array of references (pointers), all null
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   A temp = new A(i); // allocates a new A
   array.add(new A(i)); // stores the pointer to A in the list
}

A fifth = array.get(5); // This object was allocated before, and is unchanged

for(int i=10; i<1000000; i++){
      A temp = new A(i); // Allocates a new A
      array.add(); // Stores the pointer in the list
      // Internally, the List may reallocate its backing array, but it 
      // is an array of References (pointers), not the A objects themselves
}

System.out.println("it's still alive " + fifth.id); // fifth was allocated in line 4
// and is still reachable
```

The `List` never contained the instances of A themselves, only references to them. Therefore, the internal memory management of the List does not affect its contents.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your confusion is that you think that the `ArrayList` stores objects - but it doesn't, it just stores *references* ("pointers") to these objects. So when the internal array gets expanded/reallocated the object is still in the same place.

So lets take a look at your example:

- Lets assume the starting array of `array` is located at `100`
- Assume for `i=5` `new A(i)` creates an `A` at a specific location, lets say `123`. Then the fith entry of `array`'s array is `A@123`
- `fifth = array.get(5)` just copies the reference, so `fith` contains `A@123`
- When `array` has to grow its array it creates a new one, e.g. at `200`. It then copies all existing entries to the new location, including the `A@123` at position 5
- The object we created first is still at its original location `123`, so the reference `A@123` -which is contained in `fith` - is still valid

Objects only get moved during garbage collection, but that is covered in iavanish's answer.

Comment: Yup that was my initial confusion. Correct, it wasn't that hard haha.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your edit, so it's just an addition to your question:

Actually the references in Java are not at all like C++ pointers, there is an additional level of indirection involved - the addresses of objects themselves move all the time (due to compacting garbage collection), but the references remain valid.

Comment: I didn't know that, although that makes sense considering the garbage collector's magic.